# r creating text/variable name permutations without using a loop

Tags: r

I need to create variable names based on permutations of a couple of levels.
I do not want to use a loop to do it though.
Here is some example code,

```
Varname <- "Var"
Level1 <- c("A","B")
Level2 <- c(1,2,3)
```

If I write this, then I get the first level.

```
> paste0(Varname , Level1) 
[1] "VarA" "VarB"
```

I would like a method to get either of these results:

```
"VarA1" "VarA2" "VarA3" "VarB1" "VarB2" "VarB3"
"VarA1" "VarB1" "VarA2" "VarB2" "VarA3" "VarB3"
```

I thought this would work, but alas no.

```
> paste0( paste0(Varname , Level1) , Level2)
[1] "VarA1" "VarB2" "VarA3"
```

Is there a way to do this simply or a function that does this, without having to use a loop?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `expand.grid` and `paste0` you could do:

```r
d <- expand.grid(Level2, Level1)
paste0(Varname, d$Var2, d$Var1)
#> [1] "VarA1" "VarA2" "VarA3" "VarB1" "VarB2" "VarB3"
```

Comment: As a one-liner if desired, `with(expand.grid(Level2, Level1), paste0(Varname, Var2, Var1))`

Comment: @ both stefan and gregor, that works perfectly! and can be written in one line. It's very versatile for my needs. As I also use "_" separating the permutable parts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use `outer` to apply a function to all combinations of 2 variables:

```
 paste0(Varname, outer(l1, l2, paste0))
# [1] "VarA1" "VarB1" "VarA2" "VarB2" "VarA3" "VarB3"
```